# Get Sum amount against a distinct Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to get sum amount ( Field name Amount) against all the distinct values of Description fields.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TransLine](
    [TransID] [int] NULL,
    [No] [int] NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Qty] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Rate] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [TDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Kindly reply.

Comment: provide sample data and desired output so that we can help you

Comment: Just try to open this link. Thank you.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B774ux9ONqWNTUEtb0RNdFhzem8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Description, SUM(Amount) AS [SUM]
FROM dbo.TransLine
GROUP BY Description
```

You really should at least make an attempt

Comment: Sometimes Group by Description does not have all the Distinct Values...Because of "Where" claus

Comment: It's exactly what you asked for.

Comment: How could it not ? That is EXACTLY what `Group By` does. I would suggest you do some reading up on `SQL` before making statements like that, or post some data where `GROUP BY` doesn't work as you claim.

Comment: Suppose distinct values are A,B,C,..Z for the Column Description.
But when I'm selecting the records applying where clause on the TDate field, it's not containing  C,D,or etc values in the Column Description.

Comment: And obviously I would know that ? You haven't posted any queries or even mentioned that in your original question `I want to get sum amount ( Field name Amount) against all the distinct values of Description fields.`. My answer answers your original question.

Comment: What I know that Group By works for all the distinct values as per record selection...but not the all the distinct values of the Column.
Am I right Sir ?

Comment: In which case ask a new question and include ALL of the details.

Comment: I Hope that you have understood my query now. is it possible to get the result through a single T-SQL Statement ?

Comment: Link provided for sample data in my post.

What I want that it should show all the time with it Distinct Description and their respective Amount summation where is "where" Clause can be applied.

Comment: I want to write a single query which will give me the three column as 1st column for Description, 2nd for Amount 3rd for Tdate.

1. Description capture all the the distinct values and 
2. Amount field will show the accumulated sum for the respective Description, if the query finds any data otherwise zero.